# Figuring out the crypto algorithm used to store password (Java, Jira, Email This Issue)

Tags: java, postgresql, encryption, jira

I try to figure out an algorithm used to store encrypted e-mail account passwords in an add-on to Atlassian Jira (Email This Issue by META-INF). Tried several algorithms myself, searched the Internet, asked add-on's support (they decided not to reveal this information) and I'm in a dead end now.

Accounts are stored in a database table (PostgreSQL 10 specifically) as:

```
ENABLED | ENCRYPTION | FOLDER |  HOST   | ID | NAME  |                                            PASSWORD                                            | PORT | PROTOCOL | TIMEOUT |       USERNAME       | CREDENTIALS_ID | MESSAGE_POST_FUNCTION | DEBUG | UUID | PROTOCOL_LOG | TIME_INTERVAL 
--------+------------+--------+---------+----+-------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+------+----------+---------+----------------------+----------------+-----------------------+-------+------+--------------+--------------
f       | SSL        |        | 0.0.0.0 |  2 | test1 | zYxeIvwqUy2IUyWiG6yzHQ==.gdcDnnNKRkfJ+Ry/ctRghQ==.9+cm1q6fIT7Zv48Eo8mXVOeS1UoWfQxmJEN3pEOBaTY= |  995 | POP3     |   10000 | 000test1@example.com |                |                       | f     |      |              |             5 
f       | SSL        |        | 0.0.0.0 |  3 | test2 | Xkgz21cvzGRrvuD5T1XlGA==.ZVtmth4qzcXcnPm6V0yhNw==./LKHthrxTyQuEO81yR4+Z7HFW4A9ywb6zDyvTaFRkG4= |  995 | POP3     |   10000 | 000test2@example.com |                |                       | f     |      |              |             5
```

The cleartext password is *abcdefghij1234567890* in both cases. A reversible encryption is used, not hashing - the add-on uses stored passwords to authenticate to mail servers.

One could see easily there are three, dot-separated, base64-encoded segments. The last one has to be the password (as length depends on cleartext input), padded, others possibly a key and IV. I tried whatever available in *pgcrypto* add-on to PostgreSQL and consulted a Java programmer (Jira is a Java application). All to no avail.

I guess the *PASSWORD* column contains all information needed to encode/decode the plaintext, but I provide some others just in case.

It would be great to decode it using just a PostgreSQL SELECT query (possibly using an extension), but **any** help with the algorithm(s) used will be appreciated. We run Jira on Oracle Linux 8. Jira built-in mail handler (which stores password in just plain, old base64) is no longer supported in newer versions of Email This Issue. We need to hack into this to read and write the table, to avoiding storing passwords in multiple places and changing manually for dozens of accounts.

Comment: The number of possibilities makes this mostly a guessing game for the rest of us. Problems like this are typically solved by reverse engineering the password encryption software to recover the encryption algorithm. Do you have this software? Also, you seem to know definitively that *reversible encryption* is used. How do you know this? Your guesses about what those fields means make it seem like you are already on the right track and in a reverse engineering frame of mind.

Comment: @PresidentJamesK.Polk Yes, we have the add-on installed. Not sure if the license permits to share, will check this. This is called Email This Issue for JIRA, created by META-INF (com.metainf.jira.* Java class namespace). And yes, we consider reverse engineering the crypto layer, unfortunately it's gonna be costly (we have no Java programmers in our team, I only consulted externally but no success). I'm no expert in cryptography and I asked here in hope the algorithm is some kind of a "modern industry standard", and may require much less effort to figure out this way than rev.eng.

Comment: The add-on can be downloaded from https://marketplace.atlassian.com/apps/4977/email-this-issue/version-history